# source file control cvs to svn conversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, cvs, cvs2svn

Hey guys. I currently use cvs to control all my source files but want to move away from cvs to svn. Could anyone give me some pointers? I have loads of projects but they are all similar therefore would like to just have the structure:

Trunk.       /prj1,2,3, etc
Branch.    As above
Tag.         As above

I am going to be using the cvs2svn tool, have read the documentation but am still new to all of this. Can my projects all be converted with one command line instruction?

Am I right that before doing all this I have to set up an svn environment first?

Anyone with any tips would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation at http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn the differences/similarities between cvs and svn. Here's a start: [cvs-crossover-guide](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/doc/user/cvs-crossover-guide.html) and [svn for cvs users](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.forcvs.html).

From there, things should probably get clearer. The cvs2svn tool itself lets you either directly create a svn repository, write to an existing repository or create a svn dump file, depending on the command line options. This is explained in the cvs2svn docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the projects to end up in a single SVN repository, then you have to do a [multiproject conversion](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#onetoone), which requires you to use the [options file method](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html#options-file-method) to start the conversion.  Make a copy of the cvs2svn-example.options file that came with the version of cvs2svn that you are using and edit that file as described in its comments.  Then run

> cvs2svn --options=FILENAME

You don't necessarily have to set up a Subversion repository first; cvs2svn can create it for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to set up a SVN repository first. But if you already have one you can use it as the target. From the [documentation](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html):

```
-s PATH
--svnrepos PATH

Write the output of the conversion into a Subversion repository located at PATH.
This option causes a new Subversion repository to be created at PATH unless the
--existing-svnrepos option is also used.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple "idiot steps" to study and controld each pass of this process.

What is your OS ?

if you need a list of steps to do this, post a comment and I will share.