# Every update history of the CVS shift to Subversion

Tags: svn, cvs

duplicate: [source file control cvs to svn conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155197/source-file-control-cvs-to-svn-conversion)

---

I intend to change it in Subversion from CVS.
I want to shift The development history to svn, too
How to do it?

Comment: This should be retagged, as CSV is quite different from CVS. ;)

Comment: @John Y: good spotting, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

[cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/)

It tries to maintain as much history as is possible.

Answer (score 0):

google: http://mediakey.dk/~cc/howto-migrate-from-cvs-to-svn-using-cvs2svn/